# Skip model accessor

Tags: php, laravel

I got a model called Run which contains this method:

```
public function getNameAttribute($name){
    if($name == 'Eendaags')
        return $this->race_edition->race->name;

    return $this->race_edition->race->name.' '.$name;
}
```

I need this setup for laravel administrator, since alot of runs will have the same name and the only difference is the race name. But in 1 place in the website i need to get the name only, without mutating. Is this possbile?

Comment: Could you switch to using a `getNameRaceAttribute` function, intended to only be used by administrator, and set administrator to use the `->name_race` field, then ->name would be as it normally is. There is no "Get Raw Attribute" function in eloquent. relevant code: https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L1839

Comment: Tried this but it will bring other problems with it. I guess i need to hack it in administrator.

Answer (score 190, accepted):

this is the correct way

```
// that skips mutators
$model->getOriginal('name');
```

https://laravel.com/api/5.2/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html#method_getOriginal

**Edit:** **Careful!**

As Maksym Cierzniak explained in the comments, `getOriginal()` doesn't just skip mutators, it also returns the "original" value of the field at the time the object was read from the database.  So if you have since modified the model's property, this won't return your modified value, it will still return the original value.  The more consistent and reliable way to get the un-mutated value from within the model class is to retrieve it from the `attributes` property like this:

```
$this->attributes['name']
```

But be aware that `attributes` is a protected property, so you can't do that from outside the model class. In that case, you can use

```
$model->getAttributes()['name']`
```

or Maksym's technique from his comment below.

Comment: Awesome!! This is exactly what I need, thanks so much. Wish this was inside the documentation.

Comment: @SteveBauman One problem you may encounter is that ``getOriginal()`` returns the original value returned from database. So if you have ``name=something`` and you will change it and call ``getOriginal('name')`` you will still get the ``something`` value. So you may better grab the value like ``$name = array_get($model->getAttributes(), 'name');`` This way you will be sure that you have the fresh value.

Comment: `getOriginal()` is a great function for using in Observers to check what the new value was versus the old

Comment: getOriginal wont work if it does not come from the database already. However, getAttributes() work!

Comment: As of Laravel 7 you should use `getRawOriginal` instead or `getOriginal`

Answer (score 70):

since Laravel 7.x and 8.x there is a new approach to access intact attribute:

```
// that skips accessors
$model->getRawOriginal('name');
```

https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/testing/how-to-disable-casting-during-testing

Comment: Yes since Laravel 7.x `getOriginal() ` will respect casts and accessors. `getRawOriginal()` will give the raw original value.

Comment: it work for me, in 7.x laravel `getOriginal()` can't bypass accessors

Comment: This should be the correct answer

Comment: @LucasM.Oliveira if we know this answer is correct we can share it on your social network in LinkedIn or etc, please. if you can do this help others to find the answer sooner. ;)

Answer (score 3):

I was running into an issue with Eloquent accessors and form model binding - by formatting an integer with money_format, the value was no longer being loaded into the form number input field.

The workaround I am using is to create an accessor with a different name:

```
public function getRevenueDollarsAttribute($value)
{
    return money_format('$%i', $this->revenue);
}
```

This provides me with an accessor without affecting the form model binding.

Answer (score 1):

In my case for **Laravel 7.15.0**

```
public function getOriginalNameAttribute()
{
    return $this->attributes['name'];
}

// access it via
$user->originalName;
```