# Laravel 5.5 - Skip mutators in some situations

Tags: php, laravel

i use mutator and accessor for the status field, which does integer conversion to strings for the API. But in certain situations i would not like to be using string in some methods to save the models, instead of using the integers.

Ex: How could I ignore a mutator when updating a model in the controller?

Comment: There are multiple options: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17543843/skip-model-accessor https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43841752/laravel-ignore-mutators

Comment: Ok thank you. I'll test these options